# Fast Reports launch mail app using a hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

In Fast Reports v. 2017.1.2, is there any way to define a hyperlink attached to a field that launches the default mail app when clicked?

For example, I tried the following: if there is a field named "[Header.E-mail]", I added a "mailto: [Header.E-mail]" link to the field, as a hyperlink (right-click,hyperlink,custom,expression).

Answer (score 0):

You should right click on TextObject -> Hyperlink and write here something like it:
mailto:?subject=Stack%20Overflow%20Question&body=Fast%20Reports%20launch%20mail%20app%20using%20a%20hyperlink%0Ahttp%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f43321224%2f6579260%3fsem%3d2